# Batch Script: Replacing line with random number

Tags: command-line, batch-file, find-and-replace

I'm running game servers and I need a batch script that changes a number in another batch-file to a random generated number when executed.

The line that should be edited is `set _seed="255"`

The file that should be edited looks like that:

```
@ECHO OFF
:_LOOP

CLS

ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.    =================================================
ECHO.    =                                               =
ECHO.    =             Server Startup Batch              =
ECHO.    =                                               =
ECHO.    =================================================
ECHO.

set _hostname="Server Name"
set _ident="rustide"
set _port="28015"
set _rport="28016"
set _rcon="12345"
set _players="10"
set _level="Procedural Map"
set _seed="255" //This numbers should be replaced by random generated numbers [1-2147483648]
set _worldsize="1000"
set _serverimg=""
set _serverurl="https://www.website.com"
set _serverdesc="Description"
```

It would be great if somebody could help me doing this, since I'm a complete noob at it.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your "set _seed" line to be:

```
set /a _seed=%RANDOM% * 2147483647 / 32768 + 1
```

This should then generate a random number between 1-2147483647 when the script is run.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by LotPings in the comments the original max value was too large for Batch to handle so I've edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need to have it in a seperate batch file.
Because everytime the server is restarting, the Batchfile above is re-running and would generate a new seed everytime and therefore wipes the server every restart.

Comment: @dakoza Ah.. apologies I'd missed that detail when reading the question!

Comment: Your formula generates invalid numbers as batch only handles 32bit signed integers which has 2147483647 as the highest possible number.

Comment: @LotPings You're correct of course! I'm a little rusty on my batch skills evidently!